# IE7: Why do unrelated cells change width when colspan'd cells contents grow wide?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

First, please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsc7v/) in IE7. It's somewhat involved and not really worth duplicating here.

The desired behavior is that clicking the red block shows some additional details. The top row works as desired. The bottom row, in which the width of the details is greater, exhibits the behavior I'm trying to prevent.

Ideally I would like to know what's going on here but I'd settle for any answer which includes a work around that prevents the other row's column width from jumping around when the bottom row is expanded.

Testing Firefox reveals correct behavior in both cases: The bottom row details appear but no jumping occurs.  I have no ability to test in IE8 or IE9, so I don't know whether it occurs for them as well.

So, what's going on here? Why does this happen? How can I make it not jump?

The fiddle above shows my problem in its original context, but for additional narrowing here's [a version](http://jsfiddle.net/g9SQX/3/) without the javascript that tried to be more minimal. Note that removing the 25px margin from the innermost table simply hides the problem. Adding another set of cells will make it show again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE colspan bug? but not really a bug  - it was reported IE6/7/8(b1) but deemed as invalid as there is no defined behaviour for how a browser should render colspan when `table-layout: auto` is implicitly defined.

Your workaround is to set the outermost table to be `table-layout: fixed` and set the "column widths" via your very first row (`.report-header`). So take the 25px width off the `expand/expanable` cell and make the `.report-header` row have the correct widths  - you can have them default to auto if you don't want actual widths.

then you can put the nested table back to `table-layout: auto` explicitly if you want

so in essence here's code and I've put the same code into your fiddle, though I'm sorry if I lost some bits, I simplified it while testing.. if that doesn't work in IE7 now then let me know and I'll redo an entire fiddle..

#### [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/qf3F3/)

CSS:

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}

table table {
   width: auto; 
   table-layout: auto;
}

table,tr,td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

table {border: 1px solid #f00;}
/* td {border: 1px solid #00f;} was used in testing */


td.expanded, td.expandable {
    background-color:#f00;
}

tr.report-header {
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* give first row their column widths here */
tr.report-header td {width: 25px;} /* col 1 */
tr.report-header td+td {width: auto;}
tr.report-header td+td+td+td+td+td {width: 50px;} /* col 6 example */
/* end first row widths */

td.detail table, td.detail td {border: 0;}
tr.detail {display:none;}
td.detail {padding-left: 30px;}
```

Comment: You accurately identify the source of the problem and a workaround, though it's unpleasant. What still doesn't make sense to me is the cause: Even if it's undefined in the spec it surely cannot be correct to ignore the user-specified width of a cell like that when the alternative is to respect it and make the colspanned cell width funny.

Comment: ah but it can, there is no predefined behaviour for `table-layout: auto` the browsers do not know how many "passes" over a table it should take to do the calculations (if you had a huge table with colspans.. thats why they used to be so slow at rendering, nothing would render until they'd finished counting) - now if you take in dynamic behavior like JS show/hide they probably only do one 'pass back' over the table, which in this case, isn't enough - bear in mind we are talking legacy here, so I wouldn't fret it too much as it's obviously been "fixed" - just always help older IE's count ;)

Comment: and thank you.. I agree yes it's unpleasant but still x-browser, no conditional CSS required ;)